# Angular 7 sub-routing lazy-loaded modules are not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7

Accessing child module of parent module `localhost:4200/child/subchild` gives out the error in the console `localhost:4200/child/runtime.js` is not found - 404

Going to `localhost:4200/child` would load the child component but in going to `/child/subchild` would load a blank page, and the 404 error message on the console.

Versions:

- Angular (core, router) - 7.2.3
- Angular CLI - 7.3.0
- Node - 10.12

**Main Module**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "child",
    loadChildren: "./modules/child/child.module#ChildModule",
}, {
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    redirectTo: "",
}];
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        ...
    ]
})
```

**Child Module**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "",
    component: ChildComponent,
    children: [
        { path: "subchild", component: SubchildComponent }
    ]
}];
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ChildComponent, SubchildComponent],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        ...
    ]
})
```

The page page should display without any errors on going to the url:
`http://localhost:4200/child/subchild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of this issue since I changed the `base href` of `index.html`.

Reverted it from `base href='./'` to `base href='/'`.

I changed the base href this way since I was also compiling this angular project to Android using Cordova.